Does a compression-like map in Banach space always have points that resemble fixed points?
Set $X$ a Banach space and $M\subset X$ is bounded, closed and convex. Now given
$$T:M\to M, \forall x,y\in M, \|Tx-Ty\|\le\|x-y\|$$
Prove that $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists x\in M, \|Tx-x\|<\varepsilon$.
I know this proposition wants to find some properties similar to Banach fixed point theorem. When we change $\|Tx-Ty\|<\alpha\|x-y\|(\alpha<1)$ into $\|Tx-Ty\|\le\|x-y\|$, there maybe some points that move not so far.
I can give some counter examples when "bounded", "convex" are deleted respectively: just consider translation or rotation. However, I can't find any useful observation.

Fix $x_0 \in M$ and $\epsilon>0$ and consider $A_\epsilon x =\epsilon x_0 + (1-\epsilon )Tx$. Then $A_\epsilon$ is $(1-\epsilon)$ Lipschitz so it has a unique fixed point $x_\epsilon$ by the fixed point theorem. Hence $\epsilon x_0 + (1-\epsilon) Tx_\epsilon=x_\epsilon$ and so
$$ \|Tx_\epsilon -x_\epsilon \| = \epsilon \|x_0-Tx_{\epsilon}\|\le \epsilon \operatorname{diam}M. $$

Its a detail but here we are using that because $M$ is closed, its complete, and because its convex, $A_\varepsilon$ maps $M$ to $M$.

Seems that you squeezed the image $Tx$ a little bit to $x_0$ to get a compression map. It's really interesting! Is this a general technique? :)

Not sure if it's a general technique but I guess it comes "naturally" when you aim to find a map that is $(1-\epsilon)$ Lipschitz

Interestingly, when $X$ is uniformly convex then $T$ has a fixed point
